# jQuery remove empty td cells

Tags: jquery

I need to remove all empty td cells, can I do this with jQuery.

```
<td></td>

if(td == empty){
$("td").remove();
}
```

I'm not sure how to write what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the way to go: {pseudo class empty}

```
$("td:empty").remove();
```

Comment: @B2K Maybe whatever you are trying to remove isn't empty (white spaces?)

Comment: Linefeeds. It was showing as empty using Inspect Element in Safari, but view source showed the linefeeds.

Comment: @B2K But check if element is effectively empty, e.g, `$(elem).html().length` {returns 0 if empty}  Any white spaces would make it not empty. That's said, providing a jsFiddle would make your issue clearer. You could even post a question here on SO

Answer (score 3):

To remove all empty td

```
$('td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == '') {
        $(this).remove();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.each()`

```
$("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
```